I do not understand the error message displayed when I try to use QUERY() function in Google Sheets
I am trying to copy data over from one sheet to another in Google Sheets and I am currently trying to use this query in the second sheet:
=QUERY(FORM!A3:P1090; "SELECT A, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, IF(ISBLANK(K), 'TBA', K), L, M, N, O, P ORDER BY D DESC, E DESC")

The first sheet is a Google Form response sheet, queried to the second sheet so that I can apply conditional formatting, sorting, etc...
But when using the query, it gives me an error as follows:

Error
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "(" "( "" at line 1, column 37. Was expecting one of:  "where" ... "group" ... "pivot" ... "order" ... "skipping" ... "limit" ... "offset" ... "label" ... "format" ... "options" ... "," ... "" ... "+" ... "-" ... "/" ... "%" ... "" ... "/" ... "%" ... "+" ... "-" ...

I am unable to understand what this error means; I was intending that if the data from the original K column is blank (a date) it would automatically show "TBA" in the corresponding column in the second sheet.
Here is the original query, without the K blank check, which works.
=QUERY(FORM!A3:P1090; "SELECT A, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P ORDER BY D DESC, E DESC")


Faulty partis IF(ISBLANK(K), 'TBA', K). You have to stack this part as array then apply QUERY() function.

You have to calculate K column first then stack with other columns and then apply QUERY() function. Try-
=QUERY({Sheet1!A3:J1090,INDEX(IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!K3:K1090), "TBA", Sheet1!K3:K1090)),Sheet1!L3:P1090}, 
"SELECT Col1,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14,Col15,Col16 ORDER BY Col4 DESC, Col5 DESC")

It seems you ignore B Column. That is reason to select other column individually. If you want all columns then could try * like-
=QUERY({Sheet1!A3:J1090,INDEX(IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!K3:K1090), "TBA", Sheet1!K3:K1090)),Sheet1!L3:P1090}, 
"SELECT * ORDER BY Col4 DESC, Col5 DESC")



Here's one possible approach you may test out:
=let(Σ,QUERY(FORM!A3:P10, "SELECT A, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P ORDER BY D DESC, E DESC"),
 Λ,lambda(x,choosecols(Σ,x)),{Λ(sequence(9)),switch(Λ(10),,"TBA",Λ(10)),Λ(sequence(5,1,11))})

